# Add event listener to DOM element in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

I would like to add an **event listener** to the **iframe load event** inside an Angular Component.

I know I could use `ViewChild` decorator and then access the `element.nativeElement.addEventListener`

However, in order to comply with best practices when dealing with DOM inside Angular, accessing the addEventListener on the nativeElement is still considered platform independent? Or am I binding my app to pure browser app?

Thanks

Comment: provided my answer have look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want angular way then I suggest you to create directive like as below and attach it with your dom element

```
@Directive({
  selector: `[IFrame]`
})
export class IFrameDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }

  @HostListener('load', ['$event'])
  iFrameLoad(event: Event) {
    alert('IFrame loaded');
  }
}
```

`@HostListener` in directive allows you to bind event with host element with which your directive is binded.

html

```
<iframe IFrame> ..rest code
```

Answer (score 3):

did you try this ?

```
<iframe (load)="doSomething()">
```

It seems to work on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bc1r9w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).